# Python pandas, multiple dataframes in one

Tags: python, pandas

I have 100 CSV files. But I need the information of one column of all Dataframes in one Dataframe so I can make a graph out of it. When I append one column, the total Dataframe stays empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

directory = os.fsencode('xx')
total_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    if ('results' in filename):                                           
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=';')
        xCoor = temp_df.iloc[0,0]
        yCoor = temp_df.iloc[0,1]
        if (xCoor > 51 and xCoor < 52 and yCoor > 5 and yCoor < 6):
            data = temp_df['lon']
            total_df.append(data)
print(total_df[:])
```

This is the output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

## Solved:

using total_df = total_df.append(..) worked for me

Comment: look at your comparison operators in the innermost if statement

Comment: `DataFrame.append` returns a _new_ DataFrame which in this case isn't assigned to anything.

Comment: Use `total_df = total_df.append(data)` instead of just `total_df.append(data)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten into details but your `if` statement will always return `False`:

```
if (xCoor > 51 and xCoor < 52 and yCoor > 5 and yCoor < 6):
```

You have to add `>=` or `<=` somewhere.

Comment: `xcoor=51.5`, `ycoor = 5.5` ?